# IntelliJ : show program run with debugger without stopping on breakpoints?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Currently i'm on a project which has some main loop which is quite slow. Putting a breakpoint into it implicates i have to press F9 each time, and there are a lot of iterations. What i imagine is to see the program 'move' on one of my screens, without wondering if it is stuck or not.

I already have log outputs and so on, my question really focuses on this 'show debug without stop' feature.

What i imagine is to see in this main loop the current line highlighted as i it was a line-by-line execution, but without breakpoints and without going down in the subcalls.

Does any of you know a way to do something like this or wish the same thing ?

Thanks !

Comment: The answer about muting breakpoints will prevent it from stopping, but it won't show a constantly updating/moving line. It will be almost like doing a Run in the first place.

Comment: @Mikezx6r yes i'm aware of that.You can refer to the reply i made to walden in the answer he wrote just below

Answer (score 2):

Your Debug tool window has a "Mute breakpoints" control:

[image]

If you leave it ON, your application won't stop at breakpoints. You can switch it off later once you reach the point where you actually want to start debugging (e.g. mute breakpoints while the app is doing all the initial loading tasks, while you navigate to the screen you want to debug etc. and then unmute them).

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for : i wish to see the "blue line of debug" iterate over a given loop. Or something like that. Thanks for answering tho.

Comment: @Benj I had a feeling that's what you wanted, but think about it: _unless stopped_, the debugger would iterate like a million lines per second. You'd see nothing at all. So why not force it to iterate just 1 line per second? Well, maybe some people would like 2-3 seconds instead, while others would be OK with 2-3 lines per second. Some people would like for the debugger to take longer at longer lines so they have time to catch everything going on, and less at shorter, easier lines. Every debugger's solution: a step-by-step key (F8 in IDEA) so you can move the blue line at your own pace.

Comment: So the usual debugging process to see the blue line iterate over a loop is: set a breakpoint on the first line of the loop (the for/while one) and, when the app stops in that line, keep pressing F8 to execute one line at a time. You can also press F7 if you want the blue line to "step into" a method, Shift+F8 to get out of the method you're in, and F9 to let the program run until the next breakpoint or end.

Comment: If anybody would like an introduction to debugging Java programs in IntelliJ, here's a nice read: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: i know that, i'm dev since more than 10 years. As said in my question, each of the main loop subcalls takes a while, so the blue line could remain on "here is what is currently called". It is a specific case but it could be nice to have a debugging mode allowing to run like that in a given control structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure this is it but , how about disabling focus on breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but it does not seem to be linked with what i'm looking for (not really 'looking for' as it is just a though). See the reply i made to waden just up there.

Answer (score 0):

Put your cursor on the line you'd like to breakpoint and hit ctrl-shift-f8 (on a pc). You can choose not to suspend when a breakpoint is hit, and/or you can add logging that the breakpoint was triggered. If you need to, you can add a condition that must be met before the breakpoint is triggered.

Here's what this looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for : i wish to see the "blue line of debug" iterate over a given loop. Or something like that. Thanks for answering tho